# Error while creating external table in Hive using EsStorageHandler

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive

I am facing an error while creating an External Table to push the data from Hive to ElasticSearch.

**What I have done so far:**

1) Successfully set up **ElasticSearch-1.4.4** and is running.

2) Successfully set up **Hadoop1.2.1**, all the daemons are up and running.

3) Successfully set up **Hive-0.10.0**.

4) Configured **elasticsearch-hadoop-1.2.0.jar** in both **Hadoop/lib** and **Hive/lib** as well.

5) Successfully created few internal tables in Hive.

**Error coming when executing following command:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE drivers_external (
    id BIGINT, 
    firstname STRING, 
    lastname STRING, 
    vehicle STRING, 
    speed STRING) 
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'                    
TBLPROPERTIES('es.nodes'='localhost','es.resource' = 'drivers/driver');
```

**Error is:**

`Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask`

**Any Help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the resolution for it...

1) The "**elasticsearch-hadoop-1.2.0.jar**" jar I was using was bugged one. It didn't have any **hadoop/hive** packages inside it. (Found this jar on internet and just downloaded it).

Now replaced it by jar from **Maven repository "elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M1.jar"**.

2) The class `"org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.**EsStorageHandler**"` has been renamed in new elasticsearch jar as `"org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.**ESStorageHandler**"`. Note that capital **'S'** in 'ES'.

So the new hive command to create `External table` is :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE drivers_external (
       id BIGINT, 
       firstname STRING, 
       lastname STRING, 
       vehicle STRING, 
       speed STRING) 
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.ESStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES('es.nodes'='localhost','es.resource' = 'drivers/driver');
```

It Worked!